# How to use Yii query builder for creating complex query

Tags: php, mysql, yii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql query with Yii query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448711/mysql-query-with-yii-query-builder)

i am looking for making one query using Yii Query builder, in which i have to join 3-4 tables using inner join as well as i need to use IN() clause with same query, how we can do this ?

Comment: I don't know yii, but I'm going to google this and have an answer in a few minutes, which you should have done.

Comment: Using IN + table joins already sounds like a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

you're going to need to use `addInCondition`

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail

Answer (score 1):

solve your problem by run custom query as

```
        $sql = "your sql query";
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
        $command->bindParam(":param_name", param_value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result_object= $command->queryAll();
```